# Update File Blob in SQlite vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite

The issue is this. I have code that will Update A blob field in a Sqlite database. Its been modified from something that I have used and works. But when trying to get the file and into the database it doesn't, it seems to hang and I get no errors.

I have tried to trace back an issue by inserting messageboxes. It goes as far as the messagebox "File Read" and nothing else happens after that. Any Ideas?

'''

Function UpdateNoteBinary(ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal File As String)

```
    Try
        If IO.File.Exists(Me.Database) = False Then Exit Function
        If IO.File.Exists(File) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("File Does not Exist", "File Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If
        Dim SQLiteConnection1 As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & Me.Database & ";Version=3;")
        SQLiteConnection1.Open()
        Dim SQLiteInsertCommand1 As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = New SQLite.SQLiteCommand()

       
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.CommandText = "UPDATE tblNotes SET File = @File, DateModifed = @DateModifed Where ID = " & ID
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Connection = OleDbConnection1
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter("@File", System.Data.DbType.Binary, 2147483647, "File"))
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter("@DateModified", System.Data.DbType.String, 100, "DateModified"))


        Dim FileStream1 As System.IO.FileStream
        Dim FileInfo1 As System.IO.FileInfo
        MessageBox.Show("ReadingFIle")

        ' READ THE FILE INTO MEMORY
        FileInfo1 = New System.IO.FileInfo(File)
        FileStream1 = New System.IO.FileStream(File, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim Array1(CInt(FileInfo1.Length - 1)) As Byte
        Debug.WriteLine(FileStream1.Read(Array1, 0, CInt(FileInfo1.Length)))
        FileStream1.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("File Read")


        ' RUN THE COMMAND
       SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters("@DateModifed").Value = CStr(Date.Today.ToShortDateString)
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters("@File").Value = Array1

        SQLiteInsertCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        SQLiteConnection1.Close()

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Function
```

'''

Comment: Debug your code and see what actually happens. When I say "debug" I mean actually debug, i.e. set breakpoints and step through the code while examining the state. If you don't know how to debug, now is the time to learn.

Comment: I had found the error, "Index out of range". I went over my coding that I had inserted the return False before the messagebox for the exception. I should have seen it. Thankyou. Now I am on a different path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try
        If IO.File.Exists(DB) = False Then Exit Function
        
        If IO.File.Exists(File) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("File Does not Exist", "File Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If
        Dim SQLiteConnection1 As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & DB & ";Version=3;")

        Dim SQLiteInsertCommand1 As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = New SQLite.SQLiteCommand()

        'SQL LITE
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.CommandText = "UPDATE tblNotes SET NoteTitle=@NoteTitle,FileBlob=@FileBlob,DateModified=@DateModified Where ID=" & ID
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Connection = OleDbConnection1
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter("@NoteTitle", System.Data.DbType.String, 123456789, "NoteTitle"))
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter("@FileBlob", System.Data.DbType.Binary, 2147483647, "FileBlob"))
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter("@DateModified", System.Data.DbType.String, 123456789, "DateModified"))


        Dim FileStream1 As System.IO.FileStream
        Dim FileInfo1 As System.IO.FileInfo


        ' READ THE FILE INTO MEMORY
        FileInfo1 = New System.IO.FileInfo(File)
        FileStream1 = New System.IO.FileStream(File, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim Array1(CInt(FileInfo1.Length - 1)) As Byte
        Debug.WriteLine(FileStream1.Read(Array1, 0, CInt(FileInfo1.Length)))
        FileStream1.Close()



        ' RUN THE COMMAND 
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters("@NoteTitle").Value = NewTitle
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters("@FileBlob").Value = Array1
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.Parameters("@DateModified").Value = Date.Today.ToShortDateString


        SQLiteConnection1.Open()
        SQLiteInsertCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        SQLiteConnection1.Close()

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Return False


    End Try
```

Solution: was a typo in one of the fields. and cleaned up the unneeded nag boxes.